# Subtracting seconds with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a clock i want to start at 5:00.  and I just want to make a button for instance that would subtract 5 seconds so that it displays 4:55.  I'm having so much difficulty with this and JS DateTime.  I keep getting the error "format is not a function".  What am I missing?

```
var dateTime = new moment(300000);

var clock = dateTime.format('m:ss');  //Displays as 5:00

//Button Click
$scope.rewindClick = function () {
  clock = dateTime.diff(5000).format('m:ss');
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `moment.js` subtract http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

```
dateTime.subtract(5, 'seconds').format('m:ss');
```

Comment: wow thank you.. been banging my head.  i need to read docs better ty

Answer (score 1):

From the [moment.js specs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/):

> By default, moment#diff will return a number rounded towards zero
>   (down for positive, up for negative).

So, `dateTime.diff(5000)` is returning a number, which has no format() function.  As @marcelo-risse said, you'll want `dateTime.subtract()` instead.

Comment: No problem.  Moment.js has a whole lot of docs, so it can be easy sometimes to use the wrong function.